# Cursors: Reuse or re-declare

Tags: .net, sql-server, cursor

I have a code like this:

```
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c1
    FROM   table_name;

OPEN cursor_name;
FETCH cursor_name INTO @column1;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    FETCH cursor_name INTO @column1;
END

CLOSE cursor_name;
DEALLOCATE cursor_name;


 DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
        SELECT c2
        FROM   table_name;
```

Here I was wondering if it is better to reuse the same cursor instead of re-declaring it?
And, how to do so in SQL Server 2008 R2? (If it is better to re-use)

I am currently re-declaring, and it is working.

I need to re-declare it 12 times in my script.

Comment: Normally it's best to do neither :)

Comment: @podi, Any other option other than using cursors to iterate through a table?

Comment: @TheSilverBullet it depends on what you want to achieve. Most scenarios can be done using set-based sql query. What are you using cursors for.

Comment: @VarunK, to iterate through a temporary table and populate values into another temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

old thread - would love to know as well. I use dynamic SQL generating scripts based on different schemas, table and column values - you cannot use set based SQL to do this. I use cursors regularly to generate and execute scripts against different schemas using the same table structure. Most maintenance scripts use cursors and dynamic SQL. If I could use set based SQL I would but when you have 80-100 different schemas and they can be added and removed and say I need to update the indexes in each of those tables across all the schemas, cursor is really the only way - or I could write and maintain 80-100 different scripts - no thanks.  So a "Normally it's best to do neither" doesn't really help.